# Terminate child processes on ctrl-c

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, xorg, shell-script

In tiny core linux, I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ~/.X.d/freerdp.sh

rdp(){
while true
do
xfreerdp -f [IP Address]
done
}

rdp &
```

It's pretty simple; when X starts up and checks the .X.d directory (as is the case in tiny core) it finds and executes this script. The script starts up freerdp and keeps a connection open to the server by restarting it whenever it closes. As you can see from the `rdp &` line, the function is run in the background to allow X to continue its startup routine.

The problem is that whenever I cancel X with a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> the rdp process doesn't die.

I'm looking for a way to kill the process as soon as X finishes, either through:

A) a script, executed on X closing, which kills the process 
or 
B) by modifying the script to check the return value of the `xfreerdp` command.

NB - if the solution does check the return value, it must only end if the command fails to open the X display. For that reason, if you could point me to a reference for `xfreerdp` return values I'd be grateful.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+Backspace actually terminate the X process (and another process restarts it), or does it do a soft restart?

Comment: It fully terminates X. That is to say that if I run `startx` from the shell, waiting for X to start and pressing CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE means the X display closes and the shell resumes. Also note that the shell I refer to is the only TTY on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by changing the code to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ~/.X.d/freerdp.sh

while true
do
xfreerdp -f [IP Address]
done
```

Ugly, and I had to reorganise the order of script execution so this one ran last, but it kinda works...

Answer (score 0):

[See if this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525855/how-to-propagate-a-signal-through-an-arborescence-of-scripts-bash)

It seems this question is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414377/420585).

Comment: Wouldn't that rely on the process to be waiting though?

Comment: Yes, of course, I missed the point here. But now that you mentioned it, why not remove the '&' (send to background) from the "rdp &" line, and leave it on foreground, this way when X terminates your script will get killed (with it's children too).

Comment: there are scripts that the X service runs afterwards - it would be possible to change the order of script execution but it would take a lot more time & testing.